# How to preload game assets in a separate layer on the same scene

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

For my Cocos2d game, I would like to have all the assets (texture atlases and sound files) to be loaded before the main game starts. To do this, I have created a layer within my main game scene and called it preloadLayer and added this to the scene as the top most layer.

the preloadLayer consists of 2 sprites, one covers the top half of the screen and one covers the bottom half of the screen. Once all the assets are loaded, I would like the two sprite sheets to move out of the screen to reveal the main game.

he preloadlayer will load the following:

- one background png image
- one sprite sheet png image
- few sound files
- one font atlas

The questions are:

- what is the best way to achieve this?
- How do I tell the other layers that preloadlayer has finished loading.
- How do I tell the preloadLayer that everything has been loaded and it can disappear outside the screen to reveal the other layers.

For the texture atlas I am using the `[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]` and for the font atlas, I am loading it using `[CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:Str fntFile: file]`;

I would appreciate very much your help with this.

Answer (score 3):

You can preload images into the cache asynchronously, with a callback.

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImageAsync:imagePath target:self selector:@selector(imageLoaded:)];
```

The callback's signature:

```
-(void)imageLoaded:(CCTexture2D*)texture;
```

Configure your callbacks so that you can find out that your last image has loaded.  Bear in mind that if you kick off more than one image load in this manner they may not complete in the order they were started.

Comment: Thanks. Very useful. I am using ccspriteframecache to load a texture atlas with a .plist file. How does that work with CCTextureCache?

Comment: I could do with moving over to use that myself.  Anyway, it looks like CCSpriteFrameCache stores the original big texture in CCTextureCache, before doing its own stuff.  So you could try loading your atlas sprite into CCTextureCache with addImageAsync, before you then put it into CCSpriteFrameCache.  Hopefully the CCSpriteFrameCache will then skip loading it again, and its own operations will be negligible.  But you'll have to check that...

Comment: are you suggesting to pass the texture file explicitly after loading into the CCTextureCache by using the following method?- (void) addSpriteFramesWithFile: (NSString *) plist  texture:(CCTexture2D *)  texture

Comment: Maybe that would work, but I don't know because I haven't used CCSpriteFrameCache.  I was just suggesting loading it into the CCTextureCache first, and then doing exactly what you were doing before to set up your atlas.  Hopefully the time-consuming work will be done by the CCTextureCache load.  But I'm just guessing now.  Good luck :)

Comment: How can I check this? Is it by tracing through what is happening using the debugger? It is hard to know what is happening in the background.

Comment: The class reference is not covering what it is doing in great details.

Comment: Yep debugger or put in extra CCLOGs.  There's probably a bit of logic that says if(tex) { return; }, or something like that, if the texture is already in memory.

Comment: I found it. If you use the call -(void) addSpriteFramesWithFile:(NSString*)plist it actually loads the texture by itself. so inside this method, there is actually a call to CCTexture2D *texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:texturePath];

Comment: however, if you use -(void) addSpriteFramesWithFile:(NSString*)plist texture:(CCTexture2D*)texture. it does not try to load the texture for you. it assumes it is already loaded. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

use `CCTextureCache` like so:

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"myImageName"];
```

and for sounds:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]preloadBackgroundMusic:@"myMusicFile"];
// or
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]preloadEffect:@"myEffectSoundFile"];
```

effect is used for small files, background music for big files which often loop

easiest way...and it's awesome at memory management (aka..it releases itself when you receive level 1 memory warning)

check out the class references for more methods and details

edit:

just do something like:

```
if([[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"myImageName"]) {
//image loaded
}
```

what i forgot to say is that if you use the if you wont need to do the other one, so the if replaces the loading itself (but i guess that's obvious) and yet i said it just to be perfectly clear

Comment: I already know about the sharedTextureCache.(Thanks for the info for loading sounds). But my main challenge is how do I tell the other layer underneath it that this preloadLayer has finished its work and finished preloading.

Comment: i don't think you need the "IF" as Cocos will not try to add an image that has already been added. it does it's own "if" testing

Comment: you need the if. This works like this: CCTextureCache will try loading the image, if the image is in memory then it returns that image, if it's not, it loads it and then returns it.So after the if you are 100% sure you have the image loaded